# identify new line in regex

Tags: python, regex

I would like to perform some regex on the text from MAcbeth

My text is as follows:

```
Scena Secunda.

Alarum within. Enter King Malcome, Donalbaine, Lenox, with
attendants,
meeting a bleeding Captaine.

  King. What bloody man is that? he can report,
As seemeth by his plight, of the Reuolt
The newest state
```

My intention is to get the text from Enter to the full-stop.

I am trying this regular expression `Enter(.?)*\.`

But it is showing no matches. Can anybody fix my regexp?

I am trying it out in this [link](http://pythex.org/?regex=Enter(.%3F)*%5C.&test_string=Scena%20Secunda.%0A%0AAlarum%20within.%20Enter%20King%20Malcome%2C%20Donalbaine%2C%20Lenox%2C%20with%0Aattendants%2C%0Ameeting%20a%20bleeding%20Captaine.%0A%0A%20%20King.%20What%20bloody%20man%20is%20that%3F%20he%20can%20report%2C%0AAs%20seemeth%20by%20his%20plight%2C%20of%20the%20Reuolt%0AThe%20newest%20state&ignorecase=1&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: I think `Enter([^.]*)` is what you need.

Comment: Wow. great please answer it formally

Comment: Tushar already posted an answer a bit different from mine but that should work for you. He assumes you need no capture group and that there is at least 1 non-period symbol after `Enter`. If you need a more detailed answer, I can post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since @Tushar has not explained the issue you had with your regex, I decided to explain it.

Your regex - `Enter(.?)*\.` - matches a word `Enter` (literally), then optionally matches any character except a newline 0 or more times, as many as possible, up to the last period.

The problem is that your string contains a newline between the `Enter` and the period. You'd need a regex pattern to match newlines, too. To force `.` to match newline symbols, you may use `DOTALL` mode. However, it won't get you the expected result as the `*` quantifier is *greedy* (will return the longest possible substring).

So, to get the substring from `Enter` till the closest period, you can use

```
Enter([^.]*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kR2kJ8/1). If you need no capture group, remove it.

And an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/BO6HvX):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'Enter([^.]*)')
test_str = "Scena Secunda.\n\nAlarum within. Enter King Malcome, Donalbaine, Lenox, with\nattendants,\nmeeting a bleeding Captaine.\n\n  King. What bloody man is that? he can report,\nAs seemeth by his plight, of the Reuolt\nThe newest state"
print(p.findall(test_str)) # if you need the capture group text, or
# print(p.search(test_str).group()) # to get the whole first match, or
# print(re.findall(r'Enter[^.]*', test_str)) # to return all substrings from Enter till the next period
```